# awk and multilines matching (sub-regex)

Tags: awk

I am trying to use awk to parse a multiline expression. A single one of them looks like this:

```
_begin  hello world !
_attrib0    123
_attrib1    super duper
_attrib1    yet another value
_attrib2    foo
_end
```

I need to extract the value associated to _begin and _attrib1. So in the example, the awk script should return (one per line):

```
hello world ! super duper yet another value
```

The separator used is a tab (\t) character. Spaces are used only within strings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following awk script does the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { FS="\t"; }
/^_begin/      { output=$2; }
$1=="_attrib1" { output=output " " $2; }
/^_end/        { print output; }
```

You didn't specify whether you want a tab (`\t`) to be your *output* field separator.  If you do, let me know and I'll update the answer.  (Or you can; it's trivial.)

Of course, if you want a scary alternative (since we're getting close to Hallowe'en), here a solution using `sed`:

```
$ sed -ne '/^_begin./{s///;h;};/^_attrib1[^0-9]/{s///;H;x;s/\n/ /;x;};/^_end/{;g;p;}' input.txt 
hello world ! super duper yet another value
```

How does this work?  Mwaahahaa, I'm glad you asked.

- `/^_begin./{s///;h;};` -- When we see `_begin`, strip it off and store the rest of the line to sed's "hold buffer".
- `/^_attrib1[^0-9]/{s///;H;x;s/\n/ /;x;};` -- When we see `_attrib1`, strip it off, append it to the hold buffer, swap the hold buffer and pattern space, replace newlines with spaces, and swap the hold buffer and pattern space back again.
- `/^_end/{;g;p;}` -- We've reached the end, so pull the hold buffer into the pattern space and print it.

This assumes that your input field separator is just a single tab.

SO simple.  Who ever said `sed` was arcane?!

Comment: _attrib11 is making this script to fails (_attrib1 matches)

Comment: There was no `_attrib11` in the sample data you provided.  If you like, you can make conditions like `$1=="_attrib1"` instead of `/^_attrib1/` to handle that, or you can just leave it as a regex but terminate it, like `$1~/^_attrib1$/`.  I recommend the first alternate solution; always choose string matching first, regex (at least) second.

Comment: Updated my answer per your new requirement.  Also added a `sed` alternative, for your reading pleasure.

Comment: @ghoti, Your first example does not work for me. Prints only blank line. Why?

Comment: @Tedee12345 - Perhaps it has something to do with your input data.  Why not [post a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and we'll see what we can do?

Comment: @ghoti, You're right, it was a problem with the input data. I've had other than your field separator. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash 

awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} {if ($1=="_begin" || $1=="_attrib1") { output=output " " $2 }} END{print output}'
```